# messageUI.framework useful in sending pictures?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, message, snapchat

Can one use messageUI.framework in swift to send photos to someone the way snapchat does? I've done it using parse, but looking for a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use messageUI.framework for sending the photos.
 if you want snapchat functionality you should use XMPP.
This is iOS framework for XMPP
https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework also, you should require XMPP server

For XMPP server please, check [openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) and [ejabberd](https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads)